# Compute the preimage of dyadic interval via binary expansion map.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am working on an exercise about measure theory and I need to use the binary expansion of real number in the dyadic interval.

Firstly, we know that the binary expansion of real number in $[0,1]$ is a map $f:\Omega\longrightarrow [0,1]$ maps $\omega=(x_{1},\cdots, x_{n},\cdots)$ to $$f(\omega):=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x_{j}}{2^{j}}.$$

My question is then how to express $f^{-1}(E)$ if $E=(\frac{k}{2^{j}}, \frac{k+1}{2^{j}})$ is the dyadic interval.

This question is basically equivalent to finding a way to represent $x\in E$ in binary expansion.

I am not really familiar with this material, so I read several online notes. For now, the only thing I know is that this map is well-defined since the series converges (comparison test), it is surjective since any real number in $[0,1]$ has a binary expansion, but it is not injective because not all real number has a unique binary expansion (the dyadic rationals have two expansion).

I also tried to follow the post here [how to find the binary expansion of any number in the unit interval [0,1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044793/how-to-find-the-binary-expansion-of-any-number-in-the-unit-interval-0-1), but I got confused.

The post [identifying the measure $\lambda f^{-1}$ on the interval $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3840192/identifying-the-measure-lambda-f-1-on-the-interval-0-1#comment7921522_3840235) seems suggested that the binary expansion of points in the dyadic interval has only finitely many of entries, but I have no idea why it is true.

From this, [Whether a real number is a dyadic rational iff its binary expansion terminates?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404291/whether-a-real-number-is-a-dyadic-rational-iff-its-binary-expansion-terminates), I know that dyadic rational has terminating representation, but why does all the points in the dyadic intervals has finite length representation?

For now, I can only say that since dyadic rational has terminating binary expansion, and the length is the same as $j$. That is, $$\dfrac{k}{2^{j}}=0.x_{1}x_{2}\cdots x_{j}\ \ \text{and}\ \ \dfrac{k+1}{2^{j}}=0.y_{1}y_{2}\cdots y_{j}.$$ So, every $x\in E$ satisfies $$0.x_{1}x_{2}\cdots x_{j}<x<0.y_{1}y_{2}\cdots y_{j},$$ and thus $$f^{-1}(E)=f^{-1}(0.x_{1}x_{2}\cdots x_{j}, 0.y_{1}y_{2}\cdots y_{j}),$$ but then what does this mean in the space $\Omega$?.. It seems that we have many choices for the preimage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *always* numbers in any interval of the form $\ \left(\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}\right)\ $ which *don't* have binary expansions of finite length (in fact, there are always an uncountable number of irrational numbers in such an interval). Your question about the binary expansion of points in a dyadic interval having only a finite number of entries therefore implicitly assumes a false proposition.

A number $\ \alpha\ $ will lie in the interval $\ \left[\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}\right]\ $ if and only if $\ 2^n\alpha\ $ lies in the interval $\ [k,k+1]\ $—that is $\ 2^n\alpha=k+\beta\ $, where $\ \beta\ $ is  a number in the interval $\ [0,1]\ $. If $\ \displaystyle k=\sum_{i=0}^r k_i2^i\ $ is the terminating binary expansion of $\ k\ $, then $\ k+\beta\ $ will have a binary expansion $\ \displaystyle k=\sum_{i=0}^r k_i2^i+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{\beta_i}{2^i}\ $ for some sequence $\ \left(\beta_1,\beta_2,\dots, \beta_j,\dots\right)\in\Omega\ $, and $\ \alpha\ $ will have a binary expansion $\ \alpha=$$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^r \frac{k_i}{2^{n-i}}+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{\beta_i}{2^{n+i}}\ $.

Thus, corresponding to your map $\ f\rightarrow \left[0,1\right]\ $, there is also a map $\ g:\Omega\rightarrow \left[\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}\right]\ $ given by
$$
g(\omega)= \sum_{i=0}^r\frac{k_i}{2^{n-i}}+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{x_i}{2^{n+i}}=\frac{k+f(\omega)}{2^n}
$$
for $\ \omega=\left(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_j,\dots\right)\ $.

**Addendum:**

If $\ k\ge 2^n\ $, then no element of $\ \left(\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}\right)\ $ lies in the range of $\ f\ $, so $\ f^{-1}\left(\left(\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}\right)\right)=\phi\ $ in that case.

If $\ 0\le k<2^n\ $ and $\ x\in \left(\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}\right)\ $ is not a dyadic rational, then $\ x\ $  has a unique binary expansion $\ \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^r\frac{k_i}{2^{n-i}}+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{x_i}{2^{n+i}}\ $ where $\ \left(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_j,\dots\right)\in\Omega\setminus\{\mathbf{0},\mathbf{1}\}\ $, with $\ \mathbf{0}=$$(0,0,\dots,0,\dots)\ $ and $\ \mathbf{1}=(1,1,\dots,1,\dots)\ $. Therefore $\ x=f\left(\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{n-r-1},k_r,k_{r-1},\dots,k_0,x_1,x_2,\dots\right)\ $ in this case.

On the other hand if $\ x=\frac{\ell}{2^m} \in \left(\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}\right)\ $ *is* a dyadic rational with $\ \ell\ $ odd, then we must have $\ m>n\ $ and $\ 2^{m-n}k<$$\ell<$$2^{m-n}(k+1)\ $, and $\ x\ $ has exactly two binary expansions:
\begin{align}
x&=\sum_{i=0}^r\frac{k_i}{2^{n-i}}+\sum_{i=1}^{m-n-r}\frac{\ell_{m-n-r-i}}{2^{n+i}}&\text{ and}\\
x&=\sum_{i=0}^r\frac{k_i}{2^{n-i}}+\sum_{i=1}^{m-n-r-1}\frac{\ell_{m-n-r-i}}{2^{n+i}}+\sum_{i=m-n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n+i}}\ .
\end{align}
Thus, if $\ x=f(\omega)\ $, then we must have either
\begin{align}
\omega&=\\
&\big(\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{n-r-1},k_r,k_{r-1},\dots,k_0,\ell_{m-n-1},\ell_{m-n-2},\dots,\ell_1,1,0,0,\dots\big)\\
\text{or}\\
\omega&=\\
&\big(\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{n-r-1},k_r,k_{r-1},\dots,k_0,\ell_{m-n-1},\ell_{m-n-2},\dots,\ell_1,0,1,1,\dots\big)
\end{align}
Thus, $\ x=f\big(\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{n-r-1},k_r,k_{r-1},\dots,k_0,x_1,x_2,\dots\big)\ $ for some  $\ \left(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_j,\dots\right)\in\Omega\setminus\{\mathbf{0},\mathbf{1}\}\ $, in this case also.

Therefore, if $\ 0\le k<2^n\ $, then
\begin{align}
f^{-1}&\left(\left(\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}\right)\right)=\\
&\bigg\{\big(\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{n-r-1},k_r,k_{r-1},\dots,k_0,x_1,x_2,\dots\big)\,\bigg|\left(x_1,x_2,\dots\right) \in\Omega\setminus\{\mathbf{0},\mathbf{1}\}\bigg\}
\end{align}

Comment: Understood. so for any $\alpha\in E$, where $E$ is the above dyadic interval, $f^{-1}(\alpha)$ can always be expressed as your expression, so unfortunately $\alpha$ can have infinite length expansion.. Is there a way to describe the preimage $f^{-1}(E)$ following your suggestion? How do you know $k$ has terminating binary expansion?

Comment: OMG. Thank you for your brilliant solution!!!